# jquery validate input but use id for identifying fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have fields in following format:

```
<input type="text" name="cities[]" id="city_zip1"/>
<input type="text" name="cities[]" id="city_zip2"/>
<input type="text" name="cities[]" id="city_zip3"/>
```

Is there a way to make first one required by validate plugin, but to leave name as it is?
Or to make one of these three required, but to leave name as it is.

Comment: How exactly is this being validated? How is this being submitted?

Comment: Submitted like any other form, and it have one more requirement for validation that is: "required: function(element) {return $('input:checkbox[id=place_of_services1]:checked').length > 0}"

Comment: So if checkbox "place_of_services1" is checked, one of this fields should be filled in. I dont care if it any one of this fields, or just firs one.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. What does "like any other form" mean, there are several ways to submit a form... Your question is not very clear, perhaps rephrase it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done on click for example. Can be done on submit.

```
$("#checkforvalue").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("input#place_of_services:checked").val()) {
       var zipentered = false;
       $("input[id^='city_zip']").each(function() {
           if ($(this).val().length) {
               zipentered = true;
           }
       });

       if (zipentered) {
           alert("value in one of the fields");
       } else {
           alert("no value entered");
       }
   }
});
```

[js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xPchM/1/)